# asterisk 11 installation in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: installation, asterisk, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install Asterisk 11 in Ubuntu 14.04 by following http://blogs.digium.com/2012/11/14/how-to-install-asterisk-11-on-ubuntu-12-4-lts/.

I am getting following error:-

```
READ THIS OR YOUR BUILD WILL FAIL format_mp3.o
format_mp3.c:39:24: fatal error: mp3/mpg123.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [format_mp3.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [addons] Error 2
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to run the script to generate those libs:

```
./contrib/scripts/get_mp3_source.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all there are numerous dependency changes between Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 12.04. There are several options in the build interface for asterisk and understanding how they interact is key to getting a good working environment when building from source.

If you're looking to get asterisk up and running so that you can work with it I highly recommend just installing from apt-get. I have several systems in limited production roles. They are running on VMs that perform without issue or complaint. It is not necessary to build from source to run asterisk 11 on Ubuntu 14.04. Asterisk 11 is the default version in the REPO. There are plenty of add-ons that install via apt-get as well.

Just run:

```
sudo apt-cache search asterisk
```

For a quick list

I'm aware that this is not a complete answer to your question, but it would provide you with a working asterisk environment in about 30 minutes.

If you do have a reason or situation where in you absolutely must install Asterisk from sources, please provide more detailed information about how closely you followed this guide. Following it to the letter is simply not possible due to library and other changes in Ubuntu.

[This guide](http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/HTGS/Installing+FreePBX+12+on+Ubuntu+Server+14.04+LTS) from FreePBX includes complete working instructions for building Asterisk 11 on Ubuntu 14.04. You will need to allow for changes if you do not want to use the FreePBX GUI.

For beginners I highly recommend AsteriskNow or FreePBX. Be aware that Schmoozecom the company behind FreePBX is now doing development and support for AsteriskNow. This isn't a problem per say, but ...

Comment: this answer is not helping

Answer (score 0):

@Klemorai 's answer worked for me. (I don't have the points to comment on h/er post)

This is what  i did

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install asterisk dahdi asterisk-mp3
sudo apt-get install yate-qt4
```